# Synchronize brushes across different objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js, synchronize, brush, parallel-coordinates

I enhanced the original implementation of parallel coordinates https://github.com/syntagmatic/parallel-coordinates. The current visualisation looks like this http://xmashallax.xm.funpic.de/bc/test_csv.html:

[image]

Basically, there are 3 different parallel coordinate widget arranged in form of a matrix with different axes orders now.

My current target is to synchronize brushes between these rows and I don't have any idea how I could achieve this. I have 3 different objects and want them to synchronize their changes immediately (if possible). Let's say I create a brush in row 1 at cylinders. Now row 2 and 3 cylinders should apply that brush to their data.

A "brush" handler is already implemented, but my problem is to inform the other handlers with a callback or anything like this (Observer pattern crosses my mind while I'm writing this). Although I spent many hours within the original code, I still don't understand every detail and need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you should use the Observer pattern.

Comment: Could have stopped posting the question when it came to my mind lol